# JS Regex - Match each not escaped specific characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to make a Regex in JavaScript to match each not escaped specific characters.

Here I'm looking for all the `'` characters. They can be at the beginning or the end of the string, and consecutive.

E.g.:

```
'abc''abc\'abc
```

I should get 3 matchs: the 1st, 5 and 6th character. But not 11th which escaped.

Comment: So you are looking for `'` which is preceded either by no characters or by any character other than ` \ `. Can you write such regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to account for cases like `\\'` which should match, and `\\\'` which shouldn't. but you don't have lookbehinds in JS, let alone variable-length lookbehinds, so you'll have to use something else.

Use the following regex:

```
\\.|(')
```

This will match both all escaped characters and the `'` characters you're looking for, but the quotes will be in a capture group.

Look at this [demo](https://regex101.com/r/oW6sZ0/1). The matches you're interested in are in green, the ones to ignore are in blue.

Then, in JS, ignore each match object `m` where `!m[1]`.

Example:

```js
var input = "'abc''abc\\'abc \\\\' abc";
var re = /\\.|(')/g;
var m;
var positions = [];

while (m = re.exec(input)) {
  if (m[1])      
    positions.push(m.index);
}

var pos = [];
for (var i = 0; i < input.length; ++i) {
  pos.push(positions.indexOf(i) >= 0 ? "^" : " ");
}

document.getElementById("output").innerText = input + "\n" + pos.join("");
```

```html
<pre id="output"></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
var s = "'abc''abc\\'abc";
var cnt=0;
s.replace(/\\?'/g, function($0) { if ($0[0] != '\\') cnt++; return $0;});

console.log(cnt);
//=> 3
```